# Bootstrap 3 & Wordpress Vertical Menu: keep submenu open when active

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, submenu

I am developing a WordPress theme with Bootstrap 3. I have a vertical menu in the sidebar using the navbar component.  I was able to make the menu accordion-like for a submenu, so that when a parent item is clicked, the submenu expands.

My issue: How do I make that submenu stay open when one of its pages is active?

I'm hoping there's a way to do this with CSS as I know nothing about jquery.

I think I have read every other post related to this issue and experimented with the code suggestions, but I can't get anything to work or figure out how to properly apply it to my situation.  I have also searched all over the internet for the past 2 days to no avail.  I'm working remotely now, but will likely have the site running next week if that helps.

This is the code for my menu:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-header">

    <!-- Mobile Navigation -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>               
     </div>

     <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->

        <?php 
            wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'            => 'main-nav',
            'depth'           => 2,
            'container'       => 'div',
            'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'    => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'          => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
            ) );
        ?>
    </nav>
```

This is the CSS I've been working within. I modified the bootstrap.css to get the menu to act like an accordian by removing the code for small screen:

```
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------
Making the submenu stay open when clicked
------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
}
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    line-height: 21px;
}
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-image: none;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------
  Makes the navbar a verticle menu 
 ------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.navbar .nav > li {
    float: none;
    width: 200px;
    min-width: 125px;
}
.navbar .nav > li a {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing you'll have to extend the wp_bootstrap_navwalker to handle this. You'll have to list the parents of the current page and mark them active using the custom walker.

Answer (score 1):

I used that, it works pretty well !

```
 .current_page_ancestor > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```